# How to get 3 div's side by side under an angle

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have something like this in my mind to align 3 div's:
[image]
Red is div1, yellow is div2, green is div3. They are side by side, but they are under an angle.
How do I accomplish this? Via CSS?

Comment: Should I use    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) for example?

Comment: Yes, with a skew `-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(20deg, 20deg)`

Comment: But the problem is that the content would also be rotated. How do I use this as a "window" to look to the content? Assume each color is a window of content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `transform: rotate()`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.box {
  height: 100%;
  transform: skew(15deg);
}
.box:nth-child(1) {
  background: #F40C42;
  margin-left: -30px;
  flex: 0 0 150px;
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
  background: #DBF408;
  flex: 0 0 170px;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}
.box:nth-child(3) {
  background: #58F40B;
  flex: 0 0 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would the content also be rotated? How do I use this as a "window" to look to the content? Assume each color is a window of content.

Comment: You can add equal negative `transform: rotate()` on content like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/692/

Comment: Just saw it! Thanks, this is straight on what I was looking for. Clean code, never saw css coding like ".box:nth-child(3)", looks pro and efficient.